# Flutter Basics: Error: Type 'AssetBundle' not found. AssetBundle' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, assetbundle

[image]

After I added the flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1 in pubsec.yaml getting these error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your Flutter version.

At flutter_svg github issue page, there is a same issue and solution comment.

https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/610

```
If you are on stable channel, make sure Flutter version is at least 2.5.0. You need at least 2.4.0 pre for the latest version of this package
```

Comment: this resolves my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to upgrade your flutter, then this is also a viable solution,

use `flutter_svg: ^0.22.0`

https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/610#issuecomment-974614148

I'm on 2.2 and it is working very well.